# Has the word ending *dition any independent meaning?

Tags: etymology, morphemes

Does the term 'dition' has any meaning by itself or where does it derive from?

It could be found for example in many English words, like edition, addition, expedition or extradition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As jlovegren mentions, the suffix is -ition, not -dition. In fact, this is a specific case of the more general suffix -ion. In Latin, the suffix -ion generally makes nouns of action from verbs, and most of the earlier English words with variants of this suffix came from Latin or French originally. Whether the form of the suffix was -ition, -ation, etc. depended on the characteristics of the Latin verb. Nouns with -ition, for example, tend to be those where the Latin verb had a past participal form with -it- - e.g. AUDIRE --> AUDITUM --> AUDITION; ADDERE --> ADDITUM --> ADDITION.

So, in answer to your question, -ition (or -ation, -tion, -ion etc.) doesn't have a meaning, as such. Instead it has a grammatical role, as a suffix which usually turns a verbal stem into a noun of action. It developed to perform this function with native English verbs as well as Latin ones. Examples not from Latin include FLIRT --> FLIRTATION, and STARVE --> STARVATION.

Comment: just to illustrate: translatum -> translation, inventum -> invention

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is: no. This sequence of letters comes from various roots, and it even cuts right through some of them, like *-ped-* below. It is not a suffix, but merely a sequence of letters. What those words do have in common etymologically is *-t-ion*, which is in all cases a combination of the same two suffixes *-t-* and *-ion-*.

In **ex-ped-i-t-ion**, it comes from Latin *pes,* stem *ped-*, meaning "foot". The original sense of the verb *ex-ped-i-o* was "to get the foot out of [a snare]" (*-i-* is here a suffix that can turn a noun into a verb). Hence it came to connote a certain sense of (increased) movement or speed. It was already used with various similar connotations in Latin: *expedio* also meant roughly "to expedit".

The suffix *-t-* is used to form a past participle out of a verbal stem.

The suffix *-io(n-)* is generally added to the stem of a past participle (here *ex-ped-i-t-*) to form a noun of action or result: the act of expediting, or the result of expediting.

In your other examples, *-di-t-ion* comes from the Latin verb *do,* verbal stem *da-*, past participle *da-t-us/-di-t-us*, participial stem *da-t-/-di-t-*, meaning "give". In compound words, *do* also means simply "put" or "set".

In an **e-di-t-ion**, you give out your book to the public (Dutch *uit-geven*, "to give out, to publish"): Latin *e(x)* = "out".

In **ex-tra-di-t-ion**, you give someone *out* from your own group to the other side/party: from *ex-tra* = "on the outside", which is short for *extra parte*, "on the out-side", from the adjective *ex-ter* = "out", stem *ex-tr-*, from *ex* and the adjectival suffix *-ter/-tr-*).

In **ad-di-t-ion**, you give or place a certain something *next to* something else, as in adding something to a sum: from *ad* = "to, at".

But there are other words where it comes from yet other stems:

In **sed-i-t-ion**, it comes from *se(d)-* = "apart, away", plus *eo* = "to go", present stem *e-/i-*, plus the participial suffix *-t-*: "a going away (from a group), a rebellion".

Related question: [Word formation with the nominal suffix -tion: when and why do we insert an “a”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40390/word-formation-with-the-nominal-suffix-tion-when-and-why-do-we-insert-an-a)

Comment: Cerberus, what do you mean when you say "it comes from do"?

Comment: @Berthilde: The verb *do*, meaning "give", is the etymon. *Do* is the first person singular indicative, which form is normally used to name verbs in Latin as you find them in a dictionary (where English uses the  *to* + infinitive).

Comment: Yes, I understood that bit, but I'm a little confused - what is it that "comes from _do_"?

Comment: @Berthilde: Ah OK, "it" was *-dition*. I've made that bit a bit clearer.

Comment: Ah! I see now what you meant. But, as far as I can find, there is no etymological connection between _do_ and the _-dition_ suffix...

Comment: @Berthilde: I explained that above: there is no real *-dition* suffix, but in some words it comes from stem da-/di- "give" + theme vowel -i- + participial suffix -t- + actional suffix -io(n/-).

Comment: Okay, I understand now. What you're saying is that verbs whose etymology is _x_ + _do_ then become gerunds ending in _-dition_? So _edition_ is from _edo_, which in turn comes from _e_ ("out") and _do_ ("give"). But the rule is broader than that. Any Latin verb with _-dit-_ in its past participle form would give an English gerund with _-dition_. For example, _audio_ is not based on _do_, but still gives _audition_. The _d_ simply comes from the form of the verb, not specifically from a relationship to _do_. (Info. on _audio_ from Ernout and Meillet, Dict. Etym. Langue Lat.)

Comment: @Berthilde: That is true, but I think I explained the relation between -dition and specific stems well enough?, i.e. that -dition is not connected to a single stem. There is no suffix -dition, and I explained how this sequence of letters can come from entirely different stems, where I analysed the examples given by the OP, which already led to two different stems. Indeed, there are plenty of other verbs whose past participles end on -ditus, like auditus, ruditus, aditus, meditus. // Words on p.p. stem + -io are not gerunds: a gerund is formed by adding -nd-um to the present stem, addendum.

Comment: I think we broadly agree. Basically, _do_ plays no particular part in the creation of gerundial endings in English - it just happens that Latin verbs that consist etymologically of a prefix plus _do_ have _-dit-_ in their past participle and therefore will generally end with _-dition_ in their English gerund form, where others will end in _-ation_ or _-dation_, or whatever.//Yes, sorry - I should have specified in my first sentence that I meant the English gerund, not the Latin gerund.

Comment: @Berthilde: Agreed! // But the English gerund doesn't end in -ion...

Comment: Oh, Lord! I'm an idiot. I mean "noun of action". Was talking about gerunds on another question and had them on the brain. Forgive me?

Comment: @Berthilde: Haha, happens to the best!

Answer (score 2):

In all of the cited words the /d/ is part of the original Latin root:

edere: to edit

addere: to add

expedire: set free

tradere: to hand over

All of these can be nominalized with a suffix -itio(n) (e.g., editio (nom.), editionis (gen.) editionem (acc.))

Comment: Can this suffix be traced back to PIE?

Comment: @OtavioMacedo interesting question. I'm not an IE-ist, so it might be interesting to pose it as a separate question and see what we can learn from the community.

Comment: @OtavioMacedo Yes, I it is from *deh₃- "give" + *-ti- "(nominalizer)"

Comment: @OtavioMacedo Will you pose that question? :D

Comment: @Alenanno I think MarkBeadles just answered it here, that there is a PIE nominalizer *-ti-*

Comment: Yes, @Alenanno, Mark has already answered, even though my fingers are itching to ask where did that *-ti-* come from. But I think that's too far back in time to have a precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Merriam Webster lists Dition as an obsolete middle french word from the Latin dicion or dicio, a command word related to Dominion or Rule: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dition?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld.

In that case:

ex - meaning "out of" or "from" / 
ped - on foot  / 
Dition - to rule or claim dominion

this expresses far better the difference in connotation the word expedition has held historically from the word expedite.

Comment: This is an interesting finding in itself, but it does not answer the question giving explicit examples where -dition has a different origin.